# how can I cut a sphere by selecting all the faces that intersect a plane?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, faces

I have a sphere made of 512*256 faces. I'd like to be able to cut the sphere so that only a thin ring remains.
I attach a picture of the objective, I have manually selected a portion of this ring, the problem is that the sphere is so dense that selecting the faces at the poles is difficult.
My objective is to select only the faces that touch the meridian, so that the ring actually becomes thinner at the poles.
Any suggestion on the workflow? I thought I could add a plane and then select the faces that touch this plane, but I have no idea how.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). *Alt + Left click* should work just fine for this. It selects a face loop from top to bottom.

Comment: That did it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go into front view `1 on numpad`, go into wireframe mode `tab` and press `B`. Then you can select all of the faces you want. With the faces selected, press `P` and `Separate by selection`.

Comment: With this method the selection would not become thinner at the poles, the loop method is still better. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It does the same, however instead of selecting loops you select it by yourself. It works exactly the same way. :-)